# Terraform resource name from env

Tags: terraform

I have django app, when a customer purchase our app, then we initiate new droplet with `terrafrom` and when the customer left us, i mean end contract with us, we delete the instance.

But it's manuall, we delete it by this commands `terraform destroy digitalocean_droplet.myresourcename`

Want to make each resource name unqure, coz, you are saving the resource name in our database, also the `terrafrom.tfstate` saving in our database.

If we can't make resource name unqiure, then we cant create new instance too with the same name. that's why i need it pass it via enviroment vairable

This is my `main.tf` file

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    digitalocean = {
      source = "digitalocean/digitalocean"
      version = "~> 2.0"
    }
  }
}



provider "digitalocean" {
  token = var.do_token
}

resource "digitalocean_droplet" "web" {
  image  = "ubuntu-18-04-x64"
  name   = "web-1"
  region = "nyc3"
  size   = "s-1vcpu-1gb"
  ssh_keys = ["93:4e:299:3d:ee:e1:01"]
}
```

and this is my `variable.tf` file

```
variable "resource_name" {
  type = string
  default = "test"
}
```

I tried to to name resource name like this

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" var.resource_name {
      image  = "ubuntu-18-04-x64"
      name   = "web-1"
      region = "nyc3"
      size   = "s-1vcpu-1gb"
      ssh_keys = ["93:4e:299:3d:ee:e1:01"]
    }
```

But it fires me erro, can you please help me how can i do this?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is invalid Terraform syntax. You can't use variables for resource names. To accomplish this you would have to generate the .tf file through a template or something before running Terraform.